# Learning R: foreach value in col-A, list unique values in Col-B and then associated values in Col C

Tags: r

I'm learning R and have not coded in a long time (and no this is not a school assignment). My intent is to run NRC_Sentiment on notes, which I can do for only the 1st instance of the Cat. I've read doc on for loop and foreach loop (which I would've used in Perl).

I have created a data frame from a csv file

```
Cat | Sub-Cat | Notes
Cat1 | Apple | This is a fruit called apple and I love it
Cat1 | Orange | This is a fruit called orange and I don't like it
Cat2 | Tomato | This is a Veg called tomato and I like it
Cat2 | Pepper | This a Veg called pepper and I don't like it
Cat1 | Banana | This a fruit banana and I have no opinion about it
```

```
dataIn = read.csv(...)[,1:3] #Read col 1,3
df = data.frame(dataIn)
uCat = data.frame(uCatR=c(df$Cat))
uCat = unqiue(uCat)
```

I've tried for loop, but it stops at 1st instance of uCat, so any help is appreciated

In perl I could create a hash of hashes and using foreach loop through each

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is the desired result here? What for-loop are you talking about?

Comment: One of the most important and basic attributes of R is called vectorization. Most of the R calls are vectorized meaning you can apply it for a single value, say a cell or the entire vector say a data frame column. This helps R avoid loops. Check in to the vectorization concept that will help you with solution to this q as well avoid lot of others.

Comment: Can you provide an example expected output? Loos like a job for the `tidyverse` with `group_by`.

Comment: Are you using some package to run `NRC_Sentiment` ?

Comment: Output: Foreach unique cat, find all value of unique sub-cats and notes associated to them. Then apply sentiment analysis on those. For ex: Cat-1, Apple --> has sentiments associated to it, Cat-1, Orange --> has sentiments associated to it.
For Vectors, I read-up on it, though I'll need to do more, as it seems I need to understand the limitations more. In other languages, I can simply iterate and use key-value pairs to get the output I need.
Yes, I'm assuming the NRC_Sentiment pkg on notes. I've been able to do it with static values, but I'd like to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve, but it seems like you might be trying to run a sentiment analysis on the unique instances of `Notes`. You can use `map` from the `purrr` package (part of `tidyverse`). `map` will return a list, `map_df` will return a dataframe, and there are other `map` functions to return other object types.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(syuzhet)

map_df(unique(df$Notes), get_nrc_sentiment)
```

Which returns a dataframe:

```
      anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative positive
1     0            0       0    0   1       0        0     0        0        1
2     0            0       0    0   0       0        0     0        0        0
3     0            0       0    0   0       0        0     0        0        0
4     0            0       0    0   0       0        0     0        0        0
5     0            0       0    0   0       0        0     0        0        0
```

dput:

```
structure(list(Cat = c("Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat2", "Cat1"
), `Sub-Cat` = c("Apple", "Orange", "Tomato", "Pepper", "Banana"
), Notes = c("This is a fruit called apple and I love it", "This is a fruit called orange and I don't like it", 
"This is a Veg called tomato and I like it", "This a Veg called pepper and I don't like it", 
"This a fruit banana and I have no opinion about it")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Not on on unique notes, rather foreach unique Cat, associted unique sub-category & then then the associated notes. So output would like
For Cat-1, Apple, Sentiments are....
For Cat-1, Orange, Sentiments are....